# Sentiment Analysis Feature Selection based on word to label correlation

Tags: python, correlation, sentiment-analysis

In my sentiment analysis on a dataset of 194k review texts with labels (class 1-5), I am trying to reduce the features (words) based on a word to label correlation by which a classifier can be trained.

Using sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer with default parameterization, I get 86,7k features. When performing fit_transform, I got a CSR-sparse matrix which I tried to put into a data frame using toarray().

Unfortunately, an array of size (194439,86719) causes a Memory Error. I think I need it to be in the data frame in order to calculate the correlations with df.corr(). Below you find my coding:

```
corpus = data['reviewText']
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer ='word')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
content = X.toarray()         # here comes the Memory Error
vocab = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
df = pd.DataFrame(data= X.toarray(), columns=vocab)
corr = pd.Series(df.corrwith(df['overall']) > 0.6)
new_vocab = df2[corr[corr == True].index]    # should return features that we want to use
```

Is there a way to filter by correlation without having to change the format into a data frame?
Most posts that were going into the same direction of using correlation on df do not have to handle the large data amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that there are other ways to implement a feature selection based on the correlation. With SelectKBest and the scoring function f_regression.